# How to install Gnome Schedule in Cent Os 7

Tags: centos, gnome, package-management

I tried to install gnome-schedule in cent os 7  but it throws following error but the same package works well in ubuntu.

Download url:
http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/

```
gnome-schedule-2.2.2
./configure 
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for python2... /usr/bin/python2
checking for python version... 2.7
checking for python platform... linux2
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib64/python2.7/site-packages
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for PYGTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (pygtk-2.0 >= 2.6) were not met:

No package 'pygtk-2.0' found
```

Then i tried to install pygtk-2.0':

```
sudo yum install pygtk-2.0
```

No package 'pygtk-2.0' found

Please help.

Comment: For clarification there still will be error after this related to glade. I think it's something to do binding if I remember correctly. The above will not solve the problem of installing gnome-schedule but it will get you one step closer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The applicable package I found via yum is `pygtk2`, not "-2.0".

Note: questions of this nature may be better served on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install a number of additional packages to get `gnome-schedule` to work with CentOS 7.

`sudo yum install` the following:

- `pygtk2-devel`
- `gnome-python2-gconf`
- `gnome-doc-utils`
- `scrollkeeper`

Afterwards, following the instructions in the gnome-schedule install file should proceed without any errors.